# Python inserting content from multiple files into a master file to create copies of the modified files

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to insert specific lines from a file (a.xyz) to a specific location in another file(1.inp). I am able to do it for one file a.xyz , however when I try to create a for-loop to take multiple files like a.xyz and  b.xyz  and insert them into 1.inp file in way that it forms two files one containing the a.xyz in a.inp and another having b.xyz in b.inp I run into problems. So the loop iterates and puts the a.xyz into 1.inp and makes a.inp ok but when it goes again it inserts both a.xyz and b.xyz into 1.inp to create b.inp whereas I want it to put only b.xyz into a file called b.inp and so on. the files are linked below

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eCaFm_3_t7IFRlfQW5yw7oz_8HvYsFL0?usp=sharing

here is my code

```
import os
import glob
import re
import pandas as pd
file_location = os.path.join('xyz','*.xyz')
filenames =glob.glob(file_location)
print(filenames)

with open("1.inp","r") as inp:
    template = inp.readlines()
    
array_files=[]
for file in filenames:
    file_name =os.path.basename(file)
    split_filename = file_name.split('.')
    molecule_name = split_filename[0]
   
    with open (file) as f_input:
        array_files.append(f_input.read()[3:-1])
        for array in array_files:
            template.insert(81, array)

       
            with open(molecule_name+".inp", "w") as new_inpfile:  
                new_inpfile.write("\n".join(template))
```

Comment: There is some data added to list "array_files" in each iteration of outer for-loop and all the data collected until now (even if from previous iterations) is inserted in template which in turn is written to the `molecule_name+".inp"` file.

Comment: Thanks, so where should I put the array_files? if I put it inside the for loop I still see there are two  xyz files in the second inp file

Answer (score -1):

it was a simple fix I just moved the template = inp.readlines() into the for loop

```
import os
import glob
import re
import pandas as pd
file_location = os.path.join('xyz','*.xyz')
filenames =glob.glob(file_location)
print(filenames)

 
array_files=[] 
for file in filenames:
    file_name =os.path.basename(file)
    split_filename = file_name.split('.')
    molecule_name = split_filename[0]    
    
    with open (file) as f_input:
        array_files.append(f_input.read()[3:-1]) 
        for array in array_files:
            with open("1.inp","r") as inp:
                template = inp.readlines()
                template.insert(81, array) 
        
            
        with open(molecule_name+".inp", "w") as new_inpfile:  
                new_inpfile.write("\n".join(template))
```